# Where is vim man-page online and within vim help? (e.g., in vimhelp.org, and from :help)

Tags: help-system

Q1: Where can I find the vim man page online? (an up-to-date version)
Q2: Where can I find the vim man page within the vim help system? (i.e., `:help`)

http://vimhelp.org looks like the canonical up-to-date online vim documentation, but I didn't find it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem that vimhelp.org includes the man page for Vim... It looks like they're only serving and indexing the Vim `:help` files instead.

You can find the man page for Vim in its GitHub repository, it seems that besides the [nroff `vim.1` source code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/doc/vim.1) for the man page, they actually include [a text rendering for it under file `vim.man`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/doc/vim.man).

The man page is also not really directly accessible from Vim's `:help` system, since they're essentially separate. The most closely related contents to those found in the man page, including a description of command-line arguments, can be found under [`:help starting`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#starting).

Comment: And the most relevant sections are documented as `:help -<option name>`